# Injecting IConfiguration into a .NET MAUI app with Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, .net-maui

I know .NET MAUI was only released on Visual Studio 2022 today! (But I'm sure many within this community played around with the Preview build).

I was wondering whether anyone knows how to inject the *IConfiguration* object into a Blazor Server variant?

I understand there are guides when using the generic app with WPF, but not with Blazor. So far I've been having difficulty unfortunately!

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks

Comment: For injecting an IConfiguration instance into a component, you can refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#app-settings-configuration).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've tried that and Null values only ever get returned......I've tried it both during the page load and after the OnInitialized() method call.
There is also no HttpClient class in MauiProgram.cs, it seems different to regular Blazor......I've had your suggestion working for general Blazor projects, but not .NET MAUI for some reason......Reading this: https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/ it seems I have to add something to do with the Embedded resources. Not sure what to do yet though!